# How to make this binomial lattice in D3.js

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to develop a simple interative application to illustrate the [binomial option pricing model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_options_pricing_model). Essentially, I want to reproduce this graph here in D3.js:

[image]

I am thinking about using a tree layout, but this is not a tree since it has cycles. I am very new to D3.js, and this is an application that I tried to generate to teach myself D3.js. I am a bit bogged down by manually generating a lattice like this.

Is it possible to do it in D3.js?

Comment: I don't think that any of the D3 layouts would achieve this easily, so you would have to generate it yourself (i.e. draw nodes and links at the respective positions).

Comment: Very useful question. Upvote. Did you develop your application and if so, is it publicly available? I'm interested in seeing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47JfJ/1/). It contains what I believe reasonable code for generating the binomial lattice that you described.

Here is the output of the fiddle:

[image]

By changing variable `N` only, you can obtain lattices of different sizes:

[image]

I didn't include elements above and beside the lattice, since it is pretty straightforward for you to add them.

The code is not perfect, I didn't have much time to write it, but it looks to me it could be your good starting point, or serve as an example.

EDIT: Also, I didn't know when subscript 0 should be displayed after S, but you can change the behavior of the subscript to be as you need.

ADDITIONAL EDIT: If you really need math on your web page, you can use lets say [jqmath](http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html), like in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VividD/5LebL/1/), to get something like this:

[image]

and than you integrate jsmath pieces into svg with something like this:

```
var c = vis.selectAll("g") 
c.append("svg:foreignObject") 
  .attr("width", "100px") 
  .attr("height", "100px") 
  .append("body").append("p") 
  .html($(jqMath("p={e^{{rt}{/n}}-d}/{u-d}", "$$")).outerHTML());
```

Comment: Your help is greatly appreciated. I find myself lost in the way you construct the lattice. Do you mind if explain a bit how you go about developing the code you have? Thanks

Comment: I started with the simplest possible shape - a rectangle. Then added two more, but in that special position. Then added a single loop, just for rectangles on the top, they went upwards like a diagonal. Then added second loop. Then text within rects, than lines, arrows, and at the and p and 1-p. Its so called "incremental" approach - you start with what you know, and step by step move closer towards the goal. :)

Comment: I hope you can understand the code so that you can modify it. For you, I think one possible useful feature would be maybe adding click handlers for rectangles, of course if you have such requirement. I really don't know what your original task is. But adding interactivity is usually very attractive for users. However, you might want just static diagram like this.

Comment: yes, I will be adding interactive features, but mainly by providing a form for parameter updates not by clicking on the graph. Thanks!

Comment: Upvote. This is really wonderful. Do you recall how you arrived at your values for `voffset` and `hoffset`? Was it trial and error or is there a relationship between these values and the height and width of the box that I don't see? I would like to use your code and make it more flexible so that I can define the box size and the lattice lays out perfectly (as yours does).